# MAC Terminal doesn't shows folder

Tags: mac, terminal

I was installing cocoapods, and for doing so I need to access the folder where my iOS apps are, via Terminal. So, I opened the terminal and navigate to that folder...just to see Terminal doesn't find the folder.

You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEaX.jpg) what a I mean.

How could I get there using Terminal?

I am not very experienced with Unix, so please be patient...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command

```
ls -la
```

You should see it then.

Comment: Nah, the problem was that cd command doesn't allow spacing, so I had to scape the second word ("iOS\ Apps"). Without it, it was accessing the "iOS" folder, not "iOS Apps"

Comment: Had to escape the space huh?  Glad it's working! Cheers!